# Looking for an "exotic" antonym for Bane

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, archaicisms

As a game developer, I have a few ways of symbolizing the effectiveness of attacks. My engine supports elemental damage mitigation through Resistances, and elemental weakness(a Fire based attack deals more damage to you instead of being mitigated) through Aversions. I like those two words because I feel as though they entirely personify their purpose.

Having this implemented, I wanted to also include a secondary system, which, instead of being elemental based(Fire, Frost, Energy, Nature, Arcane, Holy, Shadow), it would instead be Creature Type based. I decided to call advantages vs creatures "Banes". So, if you had a Bane of 20% vs Undead, you would natively deal 20% more damage to them via all sources of damage output.

This is where my problem arises, because now I want a polar opposite of Bane. Essentially it would serve as a detrimental attribute, meaning you deal less damage to creatures of that type. I just can't seem to locate an adequate word for this "lack of effectiveness" towards monsters. I did try Googling possible antonyms, but didn't find any that clicked for me.

My question is quite simple, what would be a good word that describes this behaviour?

I need a word that essentially means "lacking strength against".

Comment: I'm cureently looking at "Potency" and "Impotency" as possible replacements.

Comment: blight or bane vs balm or boon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *[boon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boon)* isn't "exotic" enough an antonym to *bane*, then, if you're using *bane* in the sense of *poison*, an antidote to poison is a *[mithridate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mithridate)*.

Comment: I understand that "exotic" is a rather relativistic term. I just have it in my mind that it needs to be along the same lines as Bane, which, in my opinion, is a rather exotic word. The problem is that I don't actually know what I'm looking for, I just know what it should be like. And boon seems to be leaning more towards the same spectrum of Bane, which is rather ambiguous in my opinion.

Comment: A _boon_ is a blessing, a _bane_ is a curse. They sound like "polar opposites" to me.

Comment: But it depends on the context, would it not? "You have a Bane vs Undead" and "You have a Boon vs Undead" See what I mean? Also, look at my new comment.

Comment: Truthfully, I suppose Boon and Bane could work, but I would need to swap them. Boon = more damage; Bane = less damage. Still, I think I'm going to be doing Potency and Impotency anyway. I feel as though they fit better without coming off as ambiguous. I will be accepting you as the answer, only because you did help me, and that should be rewarded. I will also be naming an item mithridate, too, only because I like that word and didn't know about it previous to you mentioning it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Krythic There is quite a number of computer and desktop games ( ADnD-like, MTG and other card-collection games) that use Boon in that sense, as a "buffing" spell\ability designator. You'll fit into metagaming  space. But while bane is often used a part of word ("Nightbane"?)  boon usually is something attributed to an element or entity: "Gryff's Boon"

Comment: @Gnawme Boon doesn't bear the exact meaning of "blessing", unless used in particular context. It is 1) something beneficial, helpful 2) some favor or granted request. There is  recurrent trend in fairy tales when  elves exchange favor for favor, calling it boon, or offer a boon if mortal would win a challenge. Their legendary law to uphold their word is what gives them name of Fair Folk.